# Reducing a polynomial $ℤ\bmod 2$

Tags: finite-fields

I have the following polynomial

$$g(x)=x^6+x^5+x^4+x^2 \in ℤ \bmod 2$$

I'm having trouble finding information on how
to reduce this polynomial, Or let alone being 
able to tell if it is reducible in the first place.

If the polynomial has a root then it is reducible correct
So
$$g(0)=0^6+0^5+0^4+0^2=0 \in ℤ \bmod 2$$

$$g(1)=1^6+1^5+1^4+1^2=0 \in ℤ \bmod 2$$

So it is reducible?

EDIT: Okay it's reducible I guess i'm just confused on how to actually reduce it now.

Comment: $x^6+x^5=x^5(x+1)=0$ and $x^4+x^2=x^2(x^2+1)=x^2(x+1)^2=0$ and therefore you have the zero polynomial over $\Bbb{Z}_2.$.

Comment: This is NOT the zero polynomial. It's true its only value as function on $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is 0, but that we knew already from the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can begin with factoring out $x^2$:
$$x^6+x^5+x^4+x^2=x^2(x^4+x^3+x^2+1).$$
Now observe that $w=1$ is a root of the second factor, so it is divisible by $x-1=x+1$ (we're in characteristic $2$). Indeed,  using synthetic division, we readily obtain
$$x^6+x^5+x^4+x^2=x^2(x+1)(x^3+x+1),$$
and this last factor is irreducible since it has degree $3$ and no root in $\mathbf F_2$.